# Arranging letters of the word PROPORTIONALITY so that vowels and consonants still occupy the same places?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the letters of the word PROPORTIONALITY be arranged so that the vowels and consonants still occupy the same places?  Can someone help me understand what this question even means in terms of,so for example does it mean the specific vowels have to be in the identical space or any vowel in general has to occupy the same space.

Comment: Think about it. If the specific letters had to remain in the same place, there would be exactly one permutation. It wouldn't have mattered then to split the condition into vowels and consonants. That's a pretty good indication that that particular interpretation is not what was intended.

Comment: Should Y be treated as a vowel or a consonant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the question means that the vowels/consonants can move freely among themselves, so long as they don't go in each others spaces. In this case you can decompose the problem into two smaller problems, just thinking about the vowels and the consonants.

There are 6 vowels, with O repeated 3 times and I repeated 2 times. Therefore there are $\frac{6!}{3!2!}$ ways of arranging them amongst themselves, since O's and I's are indistinguishable.

Similarly there are $\frac{9!}{2!2!2!}$ ways of arranging the consonants, since the R, P, and T appear twice.

Multiplying these together gives a final answer of $\frac{6!9!}{(2!)^{4}3!}$

Comment: I agree with your explanation but for your answer think the numerator might be 7!8! as I believe Y is a vowel in this case.  (Of course it doesn't affect the concept.)

Comment: If the numerator is 7!8!, it changes the answer. The answer is 2721600

Answer (score 1):

The word "PR**O**P**O**RT**IO**N**A**L**I**TY" (vowels in bold) has the following structure:C-C-V-C-V-C-C-V-V-C-V-C-V-C-C where C indicates a consonant and V indicates a vowel.

The same word has 15 letters among which there are 9 consonants-P,R,P,R,T,N,L,T,Y(considering repeating same letters distinct) and 6 vowels-O,O,I,O,A,I(considering repeating same letters distinct).

The first place can be filled in 9 ways.(C)

The second place can be filled in 8 ways.(C)

The third place can be filled in 6 ways.(V)

The fourth place can be filled in 7 ways.(C)

The fifth place can be filled in 5 ways.(C)

The sixth place can be filled in 6 ways.(C)

The seventh place can be filled in 5 ways.(C)

The eight place can be filled in 4 ways.(V)

The ninth place can be filled in 3 ways.(V)

The tenth place can be filled in 4 ways.(C)

The eleventh place can be filled in 2 ways.(V)

The twelfth place can be filled in 3 ways.(C)

The thirteenth place can be filled in 1 way.(V)

The fourteenth place can be filled in 2 ways.(C)

The fifteenth place can be filled in 1 way.(C)

Thus the number of the ways in which a word can be formed in accordance with the specified rule(the number of permutations in accordance with the rule) is 9*8*6*7*5*6*5*4*3*4*2*3*1*2*1 which is equal to 261273600.

Comment: The answer is 2721600

Comment: @TripleARaz I have considered the same repeating letters distinct. If you consider them as indistinguishable then the answer comes out to be 2721600.